# Javascript Event Listener to change paragraph text onclick of button doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, event-listener

The `<p>` text doesn't change when I click the button.

An alert message shows that output and text variables are correct. But still the Inner Text of `<p>` doesn't change.

[image: See Output Picture]

Here's the HTML:

```html
<input type="text" id="msg"><br>
<button onclick="Message()">Submit</button><br>
<h2>Last Message:</h2>
<p class="msg">Message</p>
```

This is the JS:

```js
function Message(){
    var text = document.getElementById("msg").value;
    var output = document.getElementsByClassName("msg")[0].innerHTML;
    
    output = text;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to set the message directly onto the `innerHTML` property of the DOM node. Fixed example:

```js
function Message() {
    var text = document.getElementById("msg").value;
    document.getElementsByClassName("msg")[0].innerHTML = text;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="msg"><br>
<button onclick="Message()">Submit</button><br>
<h2>Last Message:</h2>
<p class="msg">Message</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your defining a variable `output` to the value of `document.getElementsByClassName("msg")[0].innerHTML` then you are changing the value of `output` to be the value of `text`.

Primitives in javascript are passed by value, not by references.

Change `var output = document.getElementsByClassName("msg")[0].innerHTML;`

to `document.getElementsByClassName("msg")[0].innerHTML = text`

Answer (score 2):

If you say something like:

```
var output = document.getElementsByClassName("msg")[0].innerHTML;
```

The value of output will just be some kind of string or similar.

Then when you change that you just change the value of the string but not the element.

What you want to do is this:

```
var output = document.getElementsByClassName("msg")[0];
output.innerHtml=text;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function Message(){
    var text = document.getElementById("msg").value;
    document.getElementsByClassName("msg").innerHTML = text;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You were super close.

Remove the `innerHTML` from `var output = document.getElementsByClassName("msg")[0].innerHTML;`

and add it here:

`output.innerHTML = text;`

So it'll look like this.

```html
<input type="text" id="msg"><br>
<button onclick="Message()">Submit</button><br>
<h2>Last Message:</h2>
<p class="msg">Message</p>

<script>
    function Message(){
    var text = document.getElementById("msg").value;
    var output = document.getElementsByClassName("msg")[0];
    
    output.innerHTML = text;
}
</script>
```